To get the previous record which is less than the given date and time
Table USER:



ID
NAME
DATE
TIME




1
ALPHI
2000-09-09
08:29:34


2
DANE
2000-09-09
07:01:02


3
SAM
2000-09-09
06:02:03


4
ALI
2000-06-01
11:11:11



To fetch the the one record, which  has the date & time just before the 2000-09-09 & 08:29:34.
SELECT
    DATE, TIME 
FROM 
    USER 
WHERE 
    DATE > 2000-09-09 
    AND TIME > 08:29:34 
ORDER BY 
    DATE, TIME 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY

But this query doesn't seem correct.
I need to get the result as
2  | DANE   |2000-09-09   | 07:01:02

It can be any date. Had to fetch the latest before the given date and time

Using a limit query should work here, but your your current date logic is slightly off.  Try using this version:
SELECT DATE, TIME 
FROM USER 
WHERE
    (DATE = '2000-09-09' AND TIME < '08:29:34') OR DATE < '2000-09-09'
ORDER BY DATE DESC, TIME DESC 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;

The WHERE clause restricts to only records on or before Sep 9th 2000 at 8:29am.  From that subset, we then order descending by date/time and retain only the first record.

Try this.
with t (ID, NAME, DATE, TIME) as
(
values
  (1, 'ALPHI', '2000-09-09', '08:29:34')
, (2, 'DANE', '2000-09-09', '07:01:02')
, (3, 'SAM', '2000-09-09', '06:02:03')
, (4, 'ALI', '2000-06-01', '11:11:11')
)
select *
from t
where timestamp(date, time) < timestamp('2000-09-09', '08:29:34')
order by date desc, time desc
limit 1




ID
NAME
DATE
TIME




2
DANE
2000-09-09
07:01:02



fiddle

select *
from USER 
where
    (DATE <= '2000-09-09' AND TIME < '08:29:34') 
order by date desc, time desc, name asc 
fetch first 1 row only;

This sql query will work in case you have multiple user records on the same date and time too.
i.e. if you have one record entry at '2000-09-09 & 08:29:34'.

This sql query will work ... No it won't, because on dates before 9th Sep all times are allowed.

hi @TimBiegeleisen
Request you to kindly correct my understanding. if the below is not proper.
This "order by name asc" will help to order the records before the sprcified date and time based on name and we can fetch the first row right.
